# PL/SQL exception handling

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling, exception

I am fairly new to pl/sql programming and have been trying to solve this from past 2 hours

This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xx_upd_new_code AS   

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
      eite.t_ep_item_ep_id,
      bite.main_item
    FROM bidw.item@demantra bite,
      t_ep_item eite
    WHERE bite.item_code = eite.item
          AND bite.main_item = bite.old_code
          AND bite.current_flag = 1
          AND bite.main_item IS NOT NULL;

  a1 c1%ROWTYPE;

  BEGIN
    xx_dbex('Starts.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');

    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO a1;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      xx_dbex('Item: ' || a1.main_item, 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');

      UPDATE t_ep_item
      SET item = a1.main_item
      WHERE t_ep_item_ep_id = a1.t_ep_item_ep_id;

      COMMIT;

      xx_dbex('Ends.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN xx_dbex('Error.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');   
  END xx_upd_new_code;
```

Whenever it gets an error the procedure ends but I want it to move to next item.
xx_debex is a procedure which stores the logs.

I have been googling, I found out that i can write two exceptions & can raise an exception if a condition is not satisfied.I tried this but it throws an error
identifier a must be declared
identifier item must be declared

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xx_upd_new_code AS   

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
      eite.t_ep_item_ep_id,
      bite.main_item
    FROM bidw.item@demantra bite,
      t_ep_item eite,
      items ite
    WHERE bite.item_code = eite.item
          AND bite.main_item = bite.old_code
          AND bite.current_flag = 1              
          AND bite.main_item IS NOT NULL;

  a1 c1%ROWTYPE;

  BEGIN
    xx_dbex('Starts.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');

    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO a1;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      IF item != a1.main_item THEN
        xx_dbex('Item: ' || a1.main_item, 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');

        UPDATE t_ep_item
        SET item = a1.main_item
        WHERE t_ep_item_ep_id = a1.t_ep_item_ep_id;
        COMMIT;

        xx_dbex('Ends.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');          
      ELSE
        RAISE a;
      END IF;

    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN a THEN xx_dbex('Error.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
      WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;   
  END xx_upd_new_code;
```

Also,somewhere it was writen i can write it in two different blocks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xx_upd_new_code AS

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT
      eite.t_ep_item_ep_id,
      bite.main_item
    FROM bidw.item@demantra bite,
      t_ep_item eite
    WHERE bite.item_code = eite.item
          AND bite.main_item = bite.old_code
          AND bite.current_flag = 1
          AND bite.main_item IS NOT NULL;

  a1 c1%ROWTYPE;

  BEGIN
    xx_dbex('Starts.', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');

    BEGIN

      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN xx_dbex('Error', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
    END;

    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO a1;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

      xx_dbex('Item: ' || a1.main_item, 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
      UPDATE t_ep_item
      SET item = a1.main_item
      WHERE t_ep_item_ep_id = a1.t_ep_item_ep_id;
      COMMIT;

    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    xx_dbex('END', 'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX'); 
  END xx_upd_new_code;
```

I am still unable to figure it out.

Comment: What does `xx_dbex` procedure do?

Answer (score 1):

divide your cursor loop in two parts/blocks. The first one will be for the part that calls the logging procedure, the other one will be for the part that updates the table. The body of your code should look something like this:

```
  BEGIN
     Open C1; 
     loop
        fetch C1 into A1;
        exit when C1%NOTFOUND
        BEGIN
           xx_dbex('Item: '||a1.main_item ,'xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
        END;
        BEGIN
           UPDATE t_ep_item 
           SET item = a1.main_item
           where t_ep_item_ep_id=a1.t_ep_item_ep_id;
           COMMIT;
           xx_dbex('Ends.','xx_upd_new_code', 'XX');
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN 
              xx_dbex('Ends.','ERROR', 'XX');
        END;
  END LOOP;
```

Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose the statements inside the loop into a new pl/sql block like this:

```
loop
 begin
  fetch ...
 exception
  when ...
 end;
end loop;
```

Btw. the logging procedure should use `pragma_autonomous_transaction` and `commit` to be independent on current transaction result.